# button_tag like link_to rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need use this code:

```
<%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-primary" do %>
 <%= t('.follow_all')%>
<% end %>
```

html output:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="button" type="submit">
 Follow all
</button>
```

if it's possible, **How can I use this button like a link, something like:**

```
<%= button_tag new_user_registration_path, :class => "btn btn-primary" do %>
     <%= t('.follow_all')%>
    <% end %>
```

I need use `button_tag` helper. I can not use `link_to` helper, or instead, if it's possible, **How can I send params from button without use a form?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `button_to`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Thank you but `button_to` generate a `<input>` button. I can not use `<input>`. I need use `<button> </button>`

Comment: Because the css style its for `<button>` you can see: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons

Comment: If you add class => 'btn btn-primary' it will work on inputs and links too. Try it.

Comment: For This example: `<%= button_to "New", :action => "new", :form_class => "new-thing" %>`, I see in the html `<form class="button_to"`...etc. I should see `<form class="new-thing"`. Where is the problem :O?

Comment: You're not separating url options from html options. Do this: `<%= button_to "New", {:action => "new"}, :form_class => "new-thing" %>`

Comment: Thank you! but with twitter bootstrap the button class is not displayed correctly. Regards!

Comment: You need to add :class => 'btn'

Answer (score 7):

What about this:

```
<%= button_tag(:type => 'button') do %>
  <% link_to t('.follow_all'), new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need a link inside `<button>` tag

Comment: @hyperrjas I think you misunderstand the purpose of the button element. Your choice is either doing this or using the button_to as Oscar suggested.

Comment: Thank you but my with framework twitter bootstrap button class is not displayed correctly!

Comment: then you need to do what Oscar suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<%= button_tag onclick: "location.href='{new_user_registration_path}'",
  type: :button, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
  <%= t('.follow_all')%>
<% end %>
```